# Expression language change with primefaces 5.2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, jsf-2.2, juel

With primefaces 5.1 it was no problem to refer only a getter in a managed bean like

```
<ui:param name="curSearch" value="#{searchBL.getSelectedSearch()}" />
```

Changed to primefaces 5.2.2 I have to do

```
<ui:param name="curSearch" value="#{searchBL.selectedSearch}" />
```

and provide a getter and a setter. Why?

Exception:

```
09:35:29,178 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-/0.0.0.0:9090-6) Error Rendering View[/views/main.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /sections/search/searchOptions.xhtml @23,111 value="#{curSearch.sortPropertyName}": /sections/search/firstSearchTab.xhtml @44,53 value="#{curSearch}": /sections/searchMaskContent.xhtml @38,74 value="#{searchBL.getSelectedSearch()}": Cannot find method 'getSelectedSearch' in 'class SearchBL$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy'
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:103) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
at org.primefaces.el.ValueExpressionAnalyzer.intercept(ValueExpressionAnalyzer.java:69) [primefaces-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
at org.primefaces.el.ValueExpressionAnalyzer.getReference(ValueExpressionAnalyzer.java:27) [primefaces-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
at org.primefaces.metadata.BeanValidationMetadataExtractor.extractPropertyDescriptor(BeanValidationMetadataExtractor.java:64) [primefaces-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
at org.primefaces.metadata.BeanValidationMetadataExtractor.extractConstraintDescriptors(BeanValidationMetadataExtractor.java:51) [primefaces-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
at org.primefaces.metadata.BeanValidationMetadataExtractor.extractDefaultConstraintDescriptors(BeanValidationMetadataExtractor.java:46) [primefaces-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
at org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabelRenderer.isNotNullDefined(OutputLabelRenderer.java:139) [primefaces-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
at org.primefaces.component.outputlabel.OutputLabelRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputLabelRenderer.java:121) [primefaces-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jsf-api-2.2.10.jar:2.2]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114) [jsf-impl-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
```

I use JUEL EL, perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? The `<ui:param>` is not from PrimeFaces. It's from Facelets. The `#{}` things are also not from PrimeFaces. It's from JSF and the container. So it's very strange that its behavior is influenced by a PrimeFaces upgrade. This is more likely a misobservation.

Comment: I use juel 2.2.7. If I only change pf version from 5.1.17 to 5.2.2, I get this exception. With 5.1.17 it works without error.

Comment: The ui:include is only one example. I had to change it on several places (to stuck at the end on another problem by the way to switch back to 5.1.17)

Comment: Looks like they changed their `ValueExpressionAnalyzer` in an incompatible way. Report an issue.

Comment: Just wondering how this can lead to 5.2 release.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the stack trace, you've a `<p:outputLabel indicateRequired="true">` which would like to check if any `@NotNull` is defined on the associated bean property. PrimeFaces is using its homegrown [`org.primefaces.el.ValueExpressionAnalyzer`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_2/src/main/java/org/primefaces/el/ValueExpressionAnalyzer.java) for that which will breakdown the EL expression representing the value of the input component associated with the label component.

However, in [5.2](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_2/src/main/java/org/primefaces/el/ValueExpressionAnalyzer.java) it was [changed](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/fc30f2530a5ef41a0e857f5fa5fc54700988b981#diff-72a7fa3296ab39282e8a2ba70141c805) as compared to [5.1](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_1/src/main/java/org/primefaces/el/ValueExpressionAnalyzer.java) as result of fix for [issue 8093](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=8093) of failing EL inspection on null nested properties. Now it doesn't distinguish method expressions anymore. Your best bet is reporting an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues) to PrimeFaces guys and tell them to peek at OmniFaces [`org.omnifaces.el.ExpressionInspector`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/8129a00aded2f9663d690ca14745371813e6508c/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/el/ExpressionInspector.java) how to do the EL expression analyzing job the right way.

Nonetheless, it's kind of strange that you're referring a readonly value as value of a required input component.